# Delete link for user isn't showing up

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to web development (I have been coding for about 6/7 months now) in hopes of building my own app. I have been reading and working of the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl.  I am on the chapter 9 section **deleting users** and am stuck. Everything works for the most part  except that the user link. It just doesn't show on the display page. The users and their avatars fine. I just can't figure out a way to get the user delete link to show.  Below is the code for the user model, the user controller, the session controller where the code current user lives and the view.

Also, when ever i take out the if statement from the user partial the delete link shows. I am not sure whats wrong since I already defined admin, and the current_user.

I would be entirely grateful for any kind of guidance. My project is also on github if the information below isn't sufficient enough

https://github.com/krischery2150/Try2150-master/tree/updating-users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your profile was deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password,
                                  :password_confirmation, :user_about_me,
                                  :birthday, :avatar, :gender)

  end

  ##Before filters method
  # Confirms that a given user is logged in. Only when these conditions are met the user will
  # be able to update or edit their page

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger]= "Please Log In"
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

# Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end


end
```

.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
    attr_accessor :remember_token

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "50x50>" }, default_url: "/images/:thumb/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    # this before_save is a callback method. What it does is before it saves the email
    #address it calls back and transforms all the letters into lower case. Had to do the indexing
    #in active record in order for the method to work
    validates :username , presence: true, length: {maximum: 250}
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      #code that ensures that a user  puts the right format for emails in signup
      #fields
    validates :email, presence: true, length:{maximum: 50},
                                      format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                      uniqueness:{ case_sensitive: false }
                                      #rails still assumes that uniquess is true
                                      #whether the user types CAMELcase or lowercase
    validates :password, presence: true, length:{maximum: 50}, allow_nil: true
    validates :user_about_me, presence: true
    validates :birthday, presence:true
    has_secure_password

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def User.digest(string)
      cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                    BCrypt::Engine.cost
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end


    ## returns a random user token
    def User.new_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    # Remember a given user to the database for use of persistent sessions

    def remember
      self.remember_token = User.new_token
      update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end

    ##returns true if given token matches the digest
    def authenticated?(remember_token)
      return false if remember_digest.nil?
      BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

    def forget
      update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end

    def log_out
      forget(current_user)
      session.delete(:user_id)
      @current_user = nil
    end
  end
```

**This is the code in the partial rendering on the index page where all users show up.**

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-offset-3" id="index-profile">

  <li class="users">
    <div class="col-xs-3 profilepic-container">
      <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
     | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
      <% end %>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The delete link in your partial has two conditions that are required to be true. The user must be an admin, and the profile must not be their own profile. So if the admin user is the only user, then no delete link will show up.

Try creating a second user and see if the delete link shows up for that user.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I have done what you suggested above but the result remained the same. However when I take the current_user.admin? off the if statement in the partial, The link showed. I am puzzled because, the console (User.new) shows that the migration for the admin boolean was successful? Ian not sure what i should be doing.